# Unable to use multiprocessing manager.dict() to share object instance

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm having problems sharing a dictionary of object instances with `multiprocessing`. I'm trying to use a `dict` that is share by a `manager`, but when I try to use the object instance as a key, it gets copied.

```
import multiprocessing

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name = "joe"):
        self.name = name
    def bark(self):
        print("woof")

mg = multiprocessing.Manager()
dt = mg.dict()
dt["a"] = 1
dt["b"] = 2
# As expected
print(dt.items()) # => [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
dt = mg.dict()
lab = Dog("carl")
print(lab) # => <__main__.Dog instance at 0x7f8d6bb869e0>
dt[lab] = 1
# But then I don't get the ID I expect
print(dt.items()) # => [(<__main__.Dog instance at 0x7f8d6bb86908>, 1)]
```

I understand the way to work around this is to use object ID as a key, but why is this happening? Is using the object ID the best solution to my problem? I noticed that this doesn't happen with a normal non-`manager` `dict()` object.

**Alternate approach**

[In the documentation for `Manager()`](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#managing-shared-state), I read that some of the problem is informing the server of changes, so I changed my code to this, but I still have the same problem where my dogs are copied, not referenced.

```
import multiprocessing

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name = "joe"):
        self.name = name
    def bark(self):
        print("woof")

mg = multiprocessing.Manager()
dt = dict()
lp = mg.list()
lp.append(dt)
print(lp)
dt["a"] = 1
dt["b"] = 2
lp[0] = dt
print(lp)
dt = dict()
lab = Dog("carl")
print(lab)
pup = Dog("steve")
print(pup)
dt[lab] = 1
dt[pup] = 2
lp[0] = dt
# Their ids change again
print(lp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `multiprocessing.Manager`, a separate server process is spawned, which is responsible for hosting all the objects created by the `Manager`. So, in order to store your `Dog` instance in the `Manager` `dict`, the instance needs to be pickled and sent to the `Manager` process. This, of course, results in an entirely separate `Dog` instance being created in the `Manager` process, so its ID won't match the ID of the `Dog` instance in your parent process. There's no way to avoid this, other than creating the `Dog` instance as a `Proxy` instance in the `Manager`, too:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager


def Manager():
    m = SyncManager()
    m.start()
    return m

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name = "joe"):
        self.name = name
    def bark(self):
        print("woof")

SyncManager.register("Dog", Dog)

mg = Manager()
dt = dict()
lp = mg.list()
lp.append(dt)
print(lp)
dt["a"] = 1 
dt["b"] = 2 
lp[0] = dt
print(lp)
dt = dict()
lab = mg.Dog("carl")
print(lab)
pup = mg.Dog("steve")
print(pup)
dt[lab] = 1 
dt[pup] = 2 
lp[0] = dt
# Their ids don't change
print(lp)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Dog instance at 0x1780098>
<__main__.Dog instance at 0x177efc8>
[{<__main__.Dog instance at 0x1780098>: 1, <__main__.Dog instance at 0x177efc8>: 2}]
```

Just keep in mind that this will make all access to your `Dog` instances in the parent process slower, since they now require IPC calls to the `Manager` process.

Comment: I am facing similar situation with `FastText` but getting `can't pickle fasttext_pybind.fasttext objects`. `FastText` is basically implemented in `C++` (https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html). The more detail is mentioned in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430747/6907424 (before applying your approach). Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation on managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) states:

> Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will
>   not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of
>   knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item,
>   you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy

While `multiprocessing` makes communication between multiple processes easy, it still can't do what the OS doesn't allow (accessing *arbitrary* memory of another process). In practice, `Manager`s work on copies of the objects, that are serialized when needed.

> I understand the way to work around this is to use object ID as a key

Note that you won't be able to get those object instances in another processes.
The "proper" way is just to reassign the objects when you change them.

Comment: For others finding this answer, there's even an example in the documentation on how to "re-assign the modified object to the container proxy".

Comment: Unfortunately, doing as recommended in the documentation doesn't solve my problem that when my normal `dict` is added to my `manager.list`, the instances of the objects aren't passed, they're copied, as you can see in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Seanny123/01d9e92fba631db07d85).